# Android studio cannot resolve symbol page_fragment (exists)

Tags: android

Currently I am trying to do this:

```
    package mko.cs.stir.ac.uk.unitconv;

    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    public class Page2Fragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2_fragment, container, false);
     }
   }
```

I've managed to fix this error before, by changing R.layout to something else, how do I find out what that something else is. Everyone says the fix is to clean, rebuild etc. But it is not in my case, how do I find the actual context path for that fragment as it is there. It is in activity_main.xml (the file with the design tab)

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports, your may have the wrong "R". You can also try to rebuild your project to regenerate your "R".

Also, in the code your pasted here, you're using
    `R.layout.page2_fragment`
and not `R.layout.page_fragment` as your title suggest it should be

Comment: I'll update the answer with the imports. Tried rebuilding various times but nothing, Also I got two classes page1_fragment and page2_fragment, I show page2_fragment but in the question title I'm just generalizing for both of them